# Is the author wrong about this RC low pass filter circuit?

Tags: passive-networks, low-pass

When reducing an RC low pass filter, the author of a text book makes the following statement: “Let us assume the application is such that, so that the voltage across RL is negligible.”

[image]

Is the book wrong when saying RL must be such that RL is much smaller than R ? Normally the filter is inserted before load but here RC filter is after RL. And why the value of RL being small relative to R matters? Im very confused, is the author wrong?

Here is the original book page:

[image]

Comment: RL parallel with ri already small whatever RL is.

Comment: I don't see how you can omit a resistor when the voltage across it is small. Can you elaborate why you're omitting \$R_L\$? The statement as is really makes preciously little sense, at that would mean the input signal from your voltage source is negligible. In fact, if your signal source really is a voltage source, you can *always* omit \$R_L\$, because it doesn't do anything (but warm up the environment).

Comment: However, none of the pictures from the book even contain R_L nor R in the configuration from your drawing, so your drawing seems to have no relation to the text you're citing.

Comment: My drawing almost same with Figure a except the diode and ri neglected for simplicity

Comment: well, yes, if you omit r_i and the diode, which are the two **important** things in that circuit, it's "almost the same". Just like an elephant looks "almost the same" as a snake, if you remove the elephant, but keep the trunk.

Comment: Author omitted those as well look at b!

Comment: Those are not related what Im asking bout

Comment: Then I don't know what you're asking about. Which is the unsimplified circuit you're talking about?

Comment: No problem if u didnt get it still, u dont have to comment every single question here.

Comment: Well, that's not how quality control works on here. Please ask clear questions. So, quality control works by users assessing how well-written a question is, if it's not, asking the poster to clarify, and if the question can't or won't be improved, vote to close it and/or vote it down. I don't think I can get a clarification out of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual text quoted is not shown, but there is enough to make an educated guess.

I suspect the intention is to consider R_L << R so that the only current through the diode affects the voltage across R_L.

The three stacked voltage sources in the second half approximate a half-wave rectified sine wave. Specifically, they represent the first three (non-zero) terms in a [Fourier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series) representation of a half-wave rectified sine wave.

If you assume an initial voltage for the capacitor you can then analyze the current waveform from the point where the diode starts to conduct.

[image]

Comment: I couldnt show the txt because there is no ebook format I could take photo of the page.

Comment: This is interesting.